# How do I copy hot keys from one computer to another

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I an running Ubuntu 20.04. I have defined a set of hot keys (keyboard shortcuts) on the computer using the setting menu.  I wish to have the same hot keys on another computer running Ubuntu 20.04.  What is the easiest way to copy the settings from one computer to another?  Is there a system file containing the settings I can simply copy?  I know I will have to install on the second computer the programs the hot keys invoke.  Thank you.

Comment: You may want to see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101226/where-does-ubuntu-store-its-keyboard-shortcut-configuration).